# simple derivative question- calc 3

Tags: calculus

how do I find/what is the derivative of this wrt x?

[image]

Comment: When you have to determine a partial derivative, you can "pretend" that any factors or terms that do not contain the variable for differentiation are constants.  So finding this partial derivative is like calculating $$ \frac{d}{dx} \ \frac{x}{(x^2 + C)^{1/2}} \ \ . $$  Once you have done that, you can restore the $ \ C \ $ as $ \ y + 4 \ $ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f_x = (x^2 + y + 4)^{-1/2} + x (-1/2) (x^2 + y + 4)^{-3/2}\,2x = \ldots
$$